# Three.js - Can't Load A Texture

Tags: javascript, image, three.js, textures

So all I want to do is grab a texture that I have saved in a folder. The error I'm getting is:
"GET file:///E:/Html/Expo%20Sites/Good%20Site/tex/dirt.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

I'm getting the texture, putting it in a variable, creating the geometry, creating the material, then creating the object and assigning the material to it. I'm new to the Three.js library so I might be missing something really obvious. Here's the code if you wanna have a look.

```
var mousePos = {x: 0.0, y: 0.0};
var windowCenterX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowCenterY = window.innerHeight / 2;  
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.shadowMapenabled = true;
renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var dirtTex = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('tex/dirt.jpg');

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1);
var floor = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 1, 10);

var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: dirtTex});

var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

var floor = new THREE.Mesh(floor, material);

var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xCCFFCC, 1.0);

var hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xCCFFCC, 0xCCFFCC, 0.6); 

cube.position.z = -5;
cube.castShadow = true;
cube.recieveShadow = true;
scene.add(cube);

floor.position.z = -5;
floor.position.y = -3;
floor.castShadow = true;
floor.recieveShadow = true;
scene.add(floor);

directionalLight.position.set(0, 1, 0);
directionalLight.shadowDarkness = 1.0;
directionalLight.castShadow = true;
directionalLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;
directionalLight.shadowCameraRight =  5;
directionalLight.shadowCameraLeft = -5;
directionalLight.shadowCameraTop =  5;
directionalLight.shadowCameraBottom = -5;
scene.add(directionalLight);

hemiLight.castShadow = true;
scene.add(hemiLight);

function Update()
{
    requestAnimationFrame(Update);

    if(mousePos.x == null || 0)
        mousePos.x = 1;
    if(mousePos.y == null || 0)
        mousePos.y = 1;

    cube.rotation.x = mousePos.y / 500;
    cube.rotation.y = mousePos.x / 500;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
Update();

document.onmousemove = function (e)
{
    if(e.pageX != null)
        mousePos.x = e.pageX;
    if(e.pageY != null)
        mousePos.y = e.pageY;
    mousePos.x = (mousePos.x - windowCenterX);
    mousePos.y = (mousePos.y - windowCenterY);
}
```

Comment: Does it give you the error on the line `var dirtTex = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('tex/dirt.jpg');`?

Answer (score 1):

> [How to run things locally](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally)
>
> If you load models or textures from external files, due to browsers'
>   "same origin policy" security restrictions, loading from a file system
>   will fail with a security exception.
>
> There are two ways how to solve this:
>
> 1) Change security for local files in a browser
>
> 2) Run files from a local server

Comment: Umm ok thanks, I really don't know what that means though. Should I put something on the google drive or what?

Comment: Either run a local server, or host everything on a server, or tell your browser to allow accessing local resources.

Comment: So how do i tell the browser to allow accessing local resources? If I tell it to allow that, will other people have to allow access? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Depends on your browser, check the link in my answer. This setting only applies to your own browser. If you distribute your work as a zipped file, users need to change their browser security settings. If you host it on a server, it will work with no configuration needed.

Comment: Thanks. How would I host it on a server? Would making it public to the web on my Google Drive account be the same as hosting it on a server? Sorry for the dumb questions, I have zero experience with networking (and anything similar to it).

Comment: Google Drive works, but you need to [do some tweaks](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en) and change all referenced url accordingly. I recommend using a [free web host](https://www.google.com/search?q=free+web+host) instead.

Answer (score 0):

To further expand upon Player's answer you have to download some sort of local server, run it, then go to wherever that server is pointed to in your browser.

To do so (because I was confused as well) you can install a local server (I used node - http://nodejs.org/download/ to download node).

After (assuming you used node from here on), to install server cd to your project directory and run in command line:

npm install http-server -g

To run:

http-server

Then go to the default local page

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

and you should see your project there.